# Print variable in linux console from JSP

Tags: java, linux, bash, jsp, console

I am calling a WAR with a JSP, and in my JSP i am saving a response.

For example:

```
<%
String parameter1=(String) request.getParameter("parameter1");
String parameter2=(String) request.getParameter("parameter2");
String responseVar = callWS(parameter1,parameter2);
out.print(responseVar);
System.out.println(responseVar);
%>
```

When i call the WAR from my Browser it works, but i need create a automatic process to get the response (And thit System.out.println set the output to the server log).

I am trying with:

```
wget http://IP:8086/myProject/myJsp?parameter1=1&parameter2=2
```

But in console i am not getting the output of the `out.print(responseVar);`

How can i get the response in my linux console to an automatic process.

Thanks.

NOTE: I have the WAR deployed in a WebLogic, but i don't have access to the logs of the server, i only have the control over the WAR.

Regards

Comment: Printing to console is `System.out.print()`. Just `out.print()` prints to the HTML page sent to the browser. This also assumes you started Tomcat from the console (in the foreground) and kept the window open. Otherwise, you won't see anything printed to console.

Comment: is it possible the result of callWs invocation is a blank string? Try out.print something solid to see whether its still empty.

Comment: Is not empty because i can see the String in my server log, and in my browser. The problem is that i need call the WAr with a bas script and get the output.